Movie about man under house arrest who thinks his neighbour is a murderer
Okay. So this movie is about a guy who is under house arrest... I can't remember why. But when he's under house arrest he like sets up wire and stuff in his garden to make sure he doesn't pass the perimeter (so his tag doesn't go off). But some kids annoy him and he chases them. This causes the police to go to his house and give him a warning. Anyway, back to the main plot. This guy begin to suspect his neighbour (an old man I think) is a murderer (can remember why he thinks that). So he tells the cops and they don't believe him. I think he phones them again later on and they search the neighbours house and they find nothing. But he's persistent that he's a killer. So he gets his friends (a girl and a guy I think) to go check his house. And it turns out he is a killer and the friends are in trouble so he goes over to the house. After an intense search scene thing the police come and they find a bunch of dead bodies in the house.
I know for a fact the film came out after 2000's... But that's about it. I really want to watch it again but I can't find it online, and I can't remember the name. Anyone able to help??

Disturbia (2007)

After his father is killed in a car accident, things unravel for Kale Brecht and he is placed under house-arrest for punching his Spanish teacher. Having nothing better to do, Kale occupies himself by spying on his neighbors. But one night, he witnesses what appears to be a murder going on in Mr. Turner's house. Kale becomes obsessed with uncovering the truth behind these murders but, after a few unsettling run-ins with Mr. Turner, it becomes a matter of life and death. And the ominous question: Who is watching whom? Written by O.G.

If I recall correctly, the main character (played by Shia Labeouf) has an ankle monitor, which is a device used to track the movements of a convict serving time outside of an institution ("house arrest"). The ankle monitor is an important plot point, since if he moves beyond a certain perimeter (say, to investigate his neighbor), police will show up quickly to arrest him and he may be forced to serve out his sentence in a prison or jail.
Note that this movie has some similarities to Rear Window (1954, itself based on a short story), but since the latter is Hitchcock, it's not really a fair comparison.
